# How to display two DB keys in two textviews

Tags: android, database

I'm following the Notes tutorial from Google http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/notepad-ex1.html

I have changed the listiew to a Gridview where I want to display all created notes with the title in textview1 and a snippet of the body in textview2.

In the tutorial it's desribed to get the KEY_TITLE and enter it in textview1 but how can I do that for both, KEY_TITLE and KEY_BODY?

```
private void fillData() {
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to, flags);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

A naive approach was to have a 2nd cursoradapter with from2 for KEY_BODY and to2 for text2 but this made text1 to be empty -> failed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second TexTView to your row layout with another id (let's call it `test2`). Then simply change the `from` and `to` arrays:

```
String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2};
```

Comment: Ah, so easy! I tried it with `+` instead of `,`, stupid me. Thanks a lot for your fast replay!